# How to make the HTML link activated by clicking on the links? AJAX call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I've created this kind of sidebar menu which loads the pages with ajax call.

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#' onclick="loadProfile()"><i class="icons user-login"></i>Customer Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' onclick="loadContacts()"><i class="icons user-login"></i>Report Incident</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' onclick="loadPage()"><i class="menu complaint-box"></i>Incidents</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

AJAX CALL

```
function loadIncidentPage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "" + AppName + "Pages/Page",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            $('#main').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using MVC. How can I make the links change color when clicked and get back to the initial style color when a different link is being clicked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the pages with ajax as well, meaning the page never does a full on refresh, you can try the following :

inside your

> loadIncidentPage

function, you can update some variable that is available to your application to say a certain URL was clicked, after that just do a [foreach](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) on all your menu items and update thier CSS are required

So if say you update the variable to

> 'help/blah/blah2'

then when you get to the each, if you find the matching link, just call .css('class','someclass') or online css.